# CollapsingToolbar cant add static footer view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to align my recyclerview to be on top of my last LinearLayout view, but I cant, it seems the recyclerview goes behind this LinearLayout, is there to have it above that LinearLayout ?

```
...

 </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabInlineLabel="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:tabIconTint="@drawable/bg_tab" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cart_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:elevation="8dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="Details"
                    android:textColor="#444"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_topay"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="$0.00"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But the output of this is this

[image]

Any idea how to put the recyclerview above the linearlayout in the CoordinatorLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding

```
  android:paddingBottom="80dp"
  android:clipToPadding="false"
```

To my recyclerview